# Field not empty but the modal is displayed - Angular

Tags: javascript, angular

I am learning Angular, I created in my page 3 fields: `Article, Quantity, Limit`.

If each field is empty, a modal appears !

For now, I have no problem, the modal appears like I want.

Now, I have two questions please:

1- If my fields are completed, and that the user clicks on `OK`, my modal appears ?? How to I change this ?

2- You think that it is possible for example that the field `quantity` to be completed obligatorily. For example, if the field `quantity` is completed and no the fields `article` and `limit`. There is no modal to display.

I am stuck on these two questions...

component.html

```html
    <br><br>
    
    <label for='quantity'>Article</label>
    <div class="input-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="article" name="article">
    </div>
    
    <label for='quantity'>Quantity</label>
    <div class="input-group">
      <input type="number" class="form-control" id="quantity" name="quantity">
    </div>
    
    <label for='quantity'>Limit</label>
    <div class="input-group">
      <input type="number" class="form-control" id="orderLimit" name="orderLimit">
    </div>
    
    <br>
    
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12">
        <button class="btn btn-lg btn-outline-primary" (click)="open(mymodal)"> ok  </button>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <!-- Modal -->
    <ng-template #mymodal let-modal>
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="modal-basic-title">Error message</h4>
        <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close button" aria-describedby="modal-title" (click)="modal.dismiss('Cross click')">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
      </button>
      </div>
    
      <div class="table-responsive">
        <table class="table table-striped">
          <thead>
    
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <td>Fields cannot be empty</td>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    
    
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-dark" (click)="modal.close('Save click')">Ok</button>
      </div>
    </ng-template>
```

component.ts

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'appBootstrap';

  closeResult: string | undefined;

  constructor(private modalService: NgbModal) {}

  open(content: any) {
    this.modalService
      .open(content, { ariaLabelledBy: 'modal-basic-title' })
      .result.then(
        result => {
          this.closeResult = `Closed with: ${result}`;
        },
        reason => {
          this.closeResult = `Dismissed ${this.getDismissReason(reason)}`;
        }
      );
  }

  private getDismissReason(reason: any): string {
    if (reason === ModalDismissReasons.ESC) {
      return 'by pressing ESC';
    } else if (reason === ModalDismissReasons.BACKDROP_CLICK) {
      return 'by clicking on a backdrop';
    } else {
      return `with: ${reason}`;
    }
  }
}
```

I can put my code below if you want:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-kr7cyd?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: If you don't want to show the modal then remove this code `(click)="open(mymodal)"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1- If my fields are completed, and that the user clicks on OK, my
> modal appears ?? How to I change this ?

No, It should not appear as you mentioned the modal should only open when  the fields are empty.

> 2- You think that it is possible for example that the field quantity
> to be completed obligatorily. For example, if the field quantity is
> completed and no the fields article and limit. There is no modal to
> display.

You can do that if you want. You can use `ngModel` and bind each input property that can help you track their values as soon as the user updates it. When you open or close the modal you can do it in the component method instead closing modal using the view reference variable.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'appBootstrap';
  article = 0, quantity = 0, orderLimit = 0;

  closeResult: string | undefined;

  constructor(private modalService: NgbModal) {}

  open(content: any) {
    this.modalService
      .open(content, { ariaLabelledBy: 'modal-basic-title' })
      .result.then(
        result => {
          this.closeResult = `Closed with: ${result}`;
        },
        reason => {
          this.closeResult = `Dismissed ${this.getDismissReason(reason)}`;
        }
      );
  }

  private getDismissReason(reason: any): string {
    if (reason === ModalDismissReasons.ESC) {
      return 'by pressing ESC';
    } else if (reason === ModalDismissReasons.BACKDROP_CLICK) {
      return 'by clicking on a backdrop';
    } else {
      return `with: ${reason}`;
    }
  }

// this should be checked everytime when user clicks 'Ok'
  openModal() {
      // check if the values are '0'
      // make sure the values come in as Number
      if (orderLimit && article && quantity) {
          // show modal
      } else {
          // no need to show modal
      }

  }
}
```

```
 <label for='quantity'>Article</label>
    <div class="input-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="article" name="article" [(ngModel)]="article">
    </div>
    
    <label for='quantity'>Quantity</label>
    <div class="input-group">
      <input type="number" class="form-control" id="quantity" [(ngModel)]="quantity" name="quantity">
    </div>
    
    <label for='quantity'>Limit</label>
    <div class="input-group">
      <input type="number" class="form-control" id="orderLimit" [(ngModel)]="orderLimit" name="orderLimit">
    </div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the time that you take for your explanations. I take note. I have an eror message with your code `Type 'Event' is not assignable to type 'number'.` -> [code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-kr7cyd?file=src/app/app.component.html), what is missing in my html?

Comment: Because you haven't added the FormsModule, I have added that check now. It is working.

Comment: Ah you saved? Because with my url there is no modification... :-( [code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-kr7cyd?file=src/app/app.component.html), you have to send me the new link, I think?

Comment: Sure let me do that

Comment: You can add `FormsModule` in the appModule and it will work. There is some issue.

Comment: Thank you Apoorva it works ! [code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-jf8sep?file=src/app/app.component.ts), thank you again for your help.